# Workflow Foundation Design Concerns/Considerations?

Tags: architecture, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation

I am reviewing this technology but have a few design concerns that made me pause a few times. Can someone help straighten me up?

1) Inside the workflow all variables are either global or activity scoped. If you want to bind them to input/output argument of an activity, then they will need to be globally scoped. And we all have dealt with managing long lasting, globally scoped variables.

My other fear is that there is great temptation with such globally scoped variables that these activity can be re-arranged with little consequence, when in fact they can't be.

Also that each activity must be aware of who is setting/modifying their input values, which is actually an alias to the globally scoped variables, violating the "Tell don't ask principle".

2) Unit Testing, I can see how each activity can be tested, but I am not seeing how the workflow as a whole can be tested yet. Eg. How am I supposed to simulate the workflow sending an email when it does not receive an input from a user after 30 days? However, I'm not comfortable leaving Unit Test out of the picture entirely, since the workflow is after all a branching logic, hence complex, hence the potential for error is too great to ignore.

3) The whole workflow foundation looks so heavily coupled ie. it's persistence + workflow + expression tree builder (kinda). I wished it were a little more elegant somehow (like the reactive framework Rx), but I gotta humbly admit, I don't know a better/faster way of doing things for long running processes.

So in conclusion, finite state machine is usually complex. Especially with feature creeps (yeah seriously think about covariant and contravariant etc.) and more so on long running processes. I'm fine with using FSM for things that rarely change eg. the C# compiler, but for something that is supposed to be fluid rather than rigid like your average business requirement, I fear that there is great temptation to abuse it and thereby making the code unmaintainable. However, workflow in a business process is just so critical, it is hard to pass up on the technology.

Am I just too defensive? What's your take? How can I avoid the pitfalls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're looking at WF 3.5, not WF 4.

> 1) Inside the workflow all variables are either global or activity
>   scoped.

WF 4 introduces container activities that create scopes.

> 2) Unit Testing.

See [Windows Workflow Foundation on CodePlex](http://wf.codeplex.com/), especially Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting. The book [Pro WF: Windows Workflow in .NET 4.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430227214) has examples of unit-testing activities. Remember that workflows and activities are interchangeable. See [WorkflowInvoker.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465567.aspx) for one way to execute a workflow (or activity) synchronously in a unit test.

> 3) The whole workflow foundation looks so heavily coupled

WF 4 decoupled persistence, for one.

And yes, workflows can be abused; see [The Danger of Centralized Workflows](http://www.udidahan.com/2011/07/13/the-danger-of-centralized-workflows/). I believe they have their place for long-running processes that involve human actors.

Comment: TrueWill, thanks for the help. However, how can we avoid "The Danger of Centralized Workflows" though? That author is right on point. The tempation is so great, to just add another feature, and then another one, and then another one, and before long you came down with a diagram exactly like the one in that post. Not to mention you lose so much tool in the process, like compile time type checking etc. which makes you think you can modify the workflow easily, when in fact you can't.

Comment: @Alwyn - and that article doesn't mention versioning of deployed workflows, which is another can of worms. There are alternatives: rules engines for shared volatile business logic, enterprise service busses for message exchange, service-oriented architecture, or writing your own shared assembly. Everything has its pros and cons. You have to evaluate what tool is best for your project. The danger lies in choosing a hammer and seeing every problem as a nail. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: The opposite danger lies in embedding workflow business logic in every application. Each program checks the persisted state and/or history of the business objects and asks itself "can I process this?" I've seen what can happen with this technique: fragile, scattered, hard-to-change logic.

Comment: Aye. That could be a problem too.  But to wrap up your suggestions :) 1) Use scope container activity to break apart the scope. 2) You're right I think we can isolate the testable block with this. Gotta research more. 3) I still don't see what's the strategy for load balancing the workflow? Is there a way for me to pass the workflow a callback function, and have it returned the workflow state so I can persist it anyhow I like it ie. encrypt decrypt, hash etc... ? Most samples seems to point that I need to declare the persistence store in the config for this.

Comment: Oh nm, I found how you can decouple the persistence layer :) http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/06/21/workflow-4-0-persistence.aspx Sweet! :D

Comment: @Alwyn: I'd recommend picking up the Pro WF book (see link above) for more details. You'll find much more material now than there was in 2009 when that article was written. Load balancing should be straightforward if workflows are deployed as WCF services. That said, I haven't done it; you could post another question on that subject. Consider using [SQL Persistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773.aspx) rather than rolling your own. For all of this, be prepared for a learning curve. Don't try to implement it on a rush project; take a month or three for a proof-of-concept.